# Mower lost power now won't restart

Tags: lawn-mower, lawn

While cutting grass I shut it down. I started it back up and it sounded like it it over surdged. When I engaged the blade the motor bogged down and had no power. I shut it down and tried to restart it but it wouldn't restart. It didn't smoke just lost power. Briggs motor.

Comment: Clean the under deck and try again.

Comment: Also check and clean the air filter.

Comment: Can not do much without model number

Comment: Out of gas, spark plug..others Look here https://www.briggsandstratton.com/na/en_us/support/manuals.html

Comment: Maybe it ran out of oil and you ruined the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the air filter to see if it's dirty or clogged. A dirty air filter can restrict airflow to the engine, leading to poor performance. If the air filter is dirty, clean or replace it as necessary.